# Create a fancytree from a subset of nodes from another tree

Tags: fancytree

**Is it possible to create a fancytree from a subset of nodes that exist in another fancytree?**

In essence what I want to accomplish is that a user clicks on a node in a tree, use the key of the node to get its structure (with all of its children) and then pass that into the source of a new tree.

So something like this:

```
var tree = $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#exampleTree");
var node = tree.getNodeByKey(key);

$("#newTree").fancytree({
    selectMode: 1,
    source: {node}
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using a combination of `subNodes = node.toDict(true)` and `tree.reload(subNodes)`.

See also [the API docs](https://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/index.html).